# Upgrading to Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory 3.10 from 3.4 alpha

Tags: c#, xamarin, portable-class-library, adal

I'm trying to upgrade my PCL projects to the latest version of ADAL from the 3.4 alpha version. My PCLs currently use Profile111, targeting .NET 4.5, Windows 8.0, Windows Phone 8.1, Xamarin.Android, Xamarin.IOS and Xamarin.IOS (classic).

I get the following error message from the nuget package manager:

> Could not install package `'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory 3.10.305231913'`. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets `'.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile111'`, but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework.

Does the latest version of ADAL no longer support Windows Phone 8.1?

Answer (score 2):

As [this blog post](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2015/12/02/new-adal-3-x-previewdevice-profile-linux-and-os-x-sample/) described Windows Phone is no longer supported in ADAL 3.x.
I had a same error message and resolved it as below steps. Please try it :)

1. Right Click (Portable) project and select property.
2. You can see property window as below. Click [Change]button.
   [click this link to watch screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwOWC.png)
3. You will see [Change Targets]popup window, so please uncheck [Windows Phone 8.1]checkbox and click [OK]button.
4. You may get an error message "The project's targets cannot be changed. The selected targets require the project to opt-into NuGet 3.0 support, however, Visual Studio cannot automatically do this for you. Please uninstall all NuGet packages and try again. If you get the error message, you can change this setting after uninstalling all packages for (portable) project from Nuget manager.
5. Retry 1-3 and You will successfully install ADAL package.

thanks,
masa

Comment: @Martin Smyllie, please try it ~

Answer (score 0):

Adal only supports universal apps and windows 8.1 support has been discontinued.